# Append one XML to another

Tags: xml, vb.net, append

Currently I need to append two XML files together, without adding new elements to the structure. I have two dataset and need to return one XML with the results of both of them

So, for example I have:

```
<Accounts>
   <Account>
   <Name> Dmmy </Name>
   </Account>
</Accounts>
```

And

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Type> asd </Type>
  <Book>
</Books>
```

And the result must be something like this :

```
<Accounts>
   <Account>
   <Name> Dmmy </Name>
   </Account>
</Accounts>
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Type> asd </Type>
  <Book>
</Books>
```

I'm with VS2010 and using Vb.net. Any ideas how Can i make this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an XML document can only have one root. Therefore the XML you show as your example wouldn't be valid.

You would have to wrap the XML in another root element.

Once you've decided what to call that, you can use any method for merging the data, depending on how the xml you have is stored.

If it's stored as a string, just do:

```
Dim newXML as string = "<rootElement>" & accountsXML & booksXML & "</rootElement>"
```

This page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387100(v=vs.100).aspx) may help with xml string literals, if that's what you're using.